# Docker container is refusing connection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker

I am using `Dockerfile` for `Nodejs` project but its returning `Connection refused` error

When I run the app without Docker it works absolutely fine.

Command I use to build and run the docker container is as follows:

```
docker build -t myapp .
docker run -it -p 8080:8080 myapp
```

Running above command runs without any error but when I hit `http://localhost:8080/test-url` it fails

My dockerfile is as follows:

```
FROM node:16.16.0-alpine
ADD . /opt
COPY . .
RUN npm install
EXPOSE 8080
RUN chmod +x /opt/deploy.sh
RUN apk update && apk add bash
CMD ["/bin/bash", "/opt/deploy.sh"]
```

And my package.json is as follows (truncated to show only script):

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "DEBUG=app* node index.js",
    "build": "rimraf build && babel-node ./src --out-dir build/src && npm run docs",
    "dev": "DEBUG=app* nodemon --exec babel-node index.js",
    "lint": "eslint 'index.js' 'src/**/*.js' 'src/index.js'",
    "docs": "apidoc -i src/ -o public/docs",
    "prepare": "husky install",
    "lint-staged": "lint-staged"
  },
```

For development I use following command which works fine::

```
npm run dev
```

For deploymeent I run `deploy.sh` which has env variables and final command as ::

```
npm run build
npm run start
```

`Even when I am trying http://localhost:8080/test-url by loging into docker interactive terminal it returns same error - Connection Refused`

Comment: Does `http://host.docker.internal:8080/test-url` work?

Comment: @rickhg12hs It returns curl: (52) Empty reply from server

Answer (score 0):

Your Port mapping looks right to me. Did you check your firewall? Maybe it is blocking the connection. It could also be helpful to test, if you can run an NGINX-Container on Port 8080. That way you can check if it is a general configuration-problem with Docker or a specific problem of your Image.

Also, did you try to set your node server to listen to 0.0.0.0 instead of localhost? I'm not sure how Docker handles IPs in the Containers, but I was thinking maybe it is called by it's internal ip. If that is the case and your server listens to localhost only, it shouldn't accept the connection.

I hope one of these things can point you in the right direction.

Comment: It depends on how you set up your networking, but with a default bridged network and an app listening on `localhost:8080` (not `0.0.0.0:8080`) inside the container would indeed not respond to requests coming from the host.